# How gcc decide to use dynamics library when creating executable?

Tags: c, gcc, dynamic, shared-libraries

I am creating an executable with this:

```
gcc elliptical.o -Llibs -lhfcal -o elliptical
```

In my libs sub folder there are:

```
libhfcal.a  libhfcal.so
```

files. My purpose is to use dynamic library but still i didnt understand how it choose `.so` file when i didnt explicitly refer it. I know it tries to use `.so` because when running executable i got
`./elliptical: error while loading shared libraries: libhfcal.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Using static library to create executable command as same as dynamics one. I know i need to use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` but my question is why compiler picked up dynamics library?

Comment: `-lhfcal` does exactly that, link to `libhfcal.so`

Comment: But i used same command for my .a file and worked. after that i created that .so file for starting dynamic linking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [gcc manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html) (emphasis mine):

> -l library
>
> Search the library named library when linking. (The second alternative with the library as a separate argument is only for POSIX compliance and is not recommended.)
>
> The -l option is passed directly to the linker by GCC. Refer to your linker documentation for exact details. The general description below applies to the GNU linker.
>
> The linker searches a standard list of directories for the library. The directories searched include several standard system directories plus any that you specify with -L.
>
> Static libraries are archives of object files, and have file names like liblibrary.a. Some targets also support shared libraries, which typically have names like liblibrary.so. **If both static and shared libraries are found, the linker gives preference to linking with the shared library unless the -static option is used.**

Comment: wow really appreciate. Now the thing is clear.